# Count the occurance of same value for the key in dictionary python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a multiple dicts in the list. I want to count the number of occurances of the certain value from the list of dicts.

Here's the list of dict:

```
a = [{"a":"data1","b":"Nill","c":"data3","d":"Nill"},{"a":"dat1","b":"dat2","c":"dat3","d":"Nill"},{"a":"sa1","b":"sa2","c":"sa3","d":"Nill"}]
```

In here, i want to count the occurance of `Nill` in the Key. How to make it possible.

Here's the code i tried:

```
from collections import Counter
a = [{"a":"data1","b":"Nill","c":"data3","d":"Nill"},{"a":"dat1","b":"dat2","c":"dat3","d":"Nill"},{"a":"sa1","b":"sa2","c":"sa3","d":"Nill"}]
s = 0
for i in a:
    d = (a[s])
    #print(d)
    q = 0
    for z in d:
        print(z)
        z1=d[z]
        #print(z)
        if z1 == "Nill":
            q = q+1
            co = {z:q}
    print(co)
```

Expected Output:

The count of `Nill` values in the list of dict

```
{a:0,b:1,c:0,d:3}
```

Comment: *Please* use more meaningful variable names than `a`, `s`, `i`, `d`, `q`, `z`, `z1` and `co`. I have no idea what any of them mean, and I'm not willing to find out.

Comment: Please Mark my answer, if it works as desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

To match the output required:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
occ = {k: list(v.values()).count('Nill') for k,v in df.to_dict().items()}
```

Comment: Certainly not the output OP wanted.

Comment: `sum([...], [])` is immensely inefficient; it's multiple orders of magnitude slower than other ways to flatten a list. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/952914/

Answer (score 2):

Try this :-

```
a = [{"a":"data1","b":"Nill","c":"data3","d":"Nill"},{"a":"dat1","b":"dat2","c":"dat3","d":"Nill"},{"a":"sa1","b":"sa2","c":"sa3","d":"Nill"}]

result_dict = {'a' : 0, 'b' : 0,'c' :0, 'd' : 0}
for i in a:
    for key, value in i.items():
        if value =="Nill":
            result_dict[key] +=1

print(result_dict)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Counter directly by counting the boolean expression with something like this that takes advantage of the fact the the counter will count `True` as 1.

```
a = [{"a":"data1","b":"Nill","c":"data3","d":"Nill"},{"a":"dat1","b":"dat2","c":"dat3","d":"Nill"},{"a":"sa1","b":"sa2","c":"sa3","d":"Nill"}]

c = Counter()
for d in a:
   c.update({k: v == 'Nill' for k, v in d.items()})

# c => Counter({'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 0, 'd': 3})
```

Comment: Was about to do it the same way! +1

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
a = [{"a":"data1","b":"Nill","c":"data3","d":"Nill"},{"a":"dat1","b":"dat2","c":"dat3","d":"Nill"},{"a":"sa1","b":"sa2","c":"sa3","d":"Nill"}]

result = {}
for sub_list in a: # loop through the list
    for key, val in sub_list.items(): # loop through the dictionary
        result[key] = result.get(key, 0) # if key not in dictionary, add it
        if val == 'Nill': # if finding 'Nill', increment that value
            result[key] += 1

for key, val in result.items(): # show result
    print(key, val)
```

Comment: @DirtyBit Done!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

c = defaultdict(int, {i:0 for i in a[0].keys()})
for i in a: 
    for k,v in i.items():
        if v=='Nill': 
            c[k] += 1
```

`dict(c)` will be your desired output.

```
{'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 0, 'd': 3}
```